# Two strings print as same but don't pass equality test?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a google script that reads in two files and checks for equality between them. When I log the values checked they are the same but my code doesn't work.

```
for(var i = 1; i < partData.length; i++){
  Logger.log("Part Data" + partData[1][2]);
  Logger.log("Name" + name);
  if(partData[1][2] === name)
  {
    temp = i + 1; 
  }
}
```

Log:

```
[18-07-13 06:56:15:876 PDT] Part DataES002-101
[18-07-13 06:56:15:877 PDT] NameES002-101
```

Why are "ES002-101" and "ES002-101" not equal?? They are from different sheets and the same font, although one is smaller and bold but that shouldn't matter right?

Comment: try `if(''+partData[1][2] === ''+name)`, it might be a type difference, but when converted to strings they are the same. `===` only returns true if both items are equal *and* the same type.

Comment: Can you check `typeof partData[1][2]` and `typeof name`

Comment: try using String(partData[1][2])

Comment: @ChristianScillitoe I tried, same thing happened, they log to the console the same way but don't work with my program and my program never increments temp despite them being equal.

Comment: @JohnDoe have you considered trailing whitespace?  This will not be obvious when printing to console but will cause a strict equality to fail.

Comment: @UllasHunka Same result as before

Comment: @AlexanderToptygin There was one space I was accidentally grabbing with substring but I got rid of it and it still isn't working

Comment: Can you include value of variable name 'partData' and 'name'?

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar I tried using .valueOf but it didn't work

Comment: I think the final answer may be the combination of trim and valueOf.  It looks like you may be comparing objects by reference and this will fail.

Comment: Try this code if (partData[1][2] === parseInt(name)) {

Comment: @AlexanderToptygin This worked thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the code as follows:

```
partData[1][2].toString().trim() == name.toString().trim()
```

If still doesn't work then try using the following:

```
partData[1][2].toString().replace(/ /g,'')==name.toString().replace(/ /g,'')
```

I have just tried converting the objects into the string and replaced all spaces to compare. But you should be careful using the above condition as this doesn't compare the real strings.

Comment: The log of the typeof returns string for both

Comment: In this case, the above should work. If works please upvote.